# Changing column values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to change the value of a `Cabin` column in my data frame.

Here's my dataframe:

[image]

I would like to assign the value to be 1, where the `Cabin` is not equal to `0`. That means the value of `C85, C123, E46` should be `1` and rest of the values should be same.

This is the code, but I am getting a value error.

```
if df_train.Cabin != 0:
   df_train.Cabin = 1
else:
   df_train.Cabin = 0
```

Comment: Can you post your dataframe *not* as an image, but as text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
df['newCabin'] = np.where(df['cabin'] != 0, 1, df['cabin'])

print(df)
cabin newCabin
    0        0
  C85        1
    0        0
 C123        1
    0        0
    0        0
```

and if you dont want extra new column, then you can do this one too

```
df['cabin'] = np.where(df['cabin'] != 0, 1, df['cabin'])
print(df)
cabin
    0
    1
    0
    1
    0
    0
```

Comment: df['cabin'] = np.where(df['cabin'] != '0', 1, df['cabin']) instead of this f['cabin'] = np.where(df['cabin'] != 0, 1, df['cabin'])

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: I had 0 as a string in my dataframe, thatswhy I used the quote.

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df_train["new_Cabin"] = df_train["Cabin"].apply(lambda x: x != 0).astype(int)
```

Also, you can compare column to zero:

```
df["new_Cabin"] = (df_train["Cabin"] != 0).astype(int)
```

Comment: All the values are being converted to 1. I dont want to convert 0's to 1.

Comment: @Vic13 Maybe, you need to remove quotes `"` around 0: `x != 0` instead of `x != "0"`

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

simple oneliner that should work

```
df_train['cabin'][df_train['cabin'] != '0'] = 1
```